# C# program for automating excel with before close event handler not saving edited excel file

Tags: c#, c++, excel, event-handling

I wanted to avoid Excel ole calls through my c++ code to launch excel. I also wanted to wait for excel to be closed before proceeding. For that I implemented following C# program and I use system call to execute it. It works but any changes I make to the excel are not getting saved. I am not sure whats happening. 
Can you please help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace excelHandler
{
    class Program
    {
        private static bool isClosed = false;

        private static void app_WorkbookBeforeClose(Excel.Workbook wb, ref bool cancel)
        {
           if (!wb.Saved)
           {
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save the " +
                    "changes you made to " + wb.FullName + "?", "Blizzard Excel",
                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Warning, 
                    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 
                    MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);

                switch (result)
                {
                    case DialogResult.Yes:
                        wb.Save();
                        break;

                    case DialogResult.Cancel:
                        cancel = true;
                        break;

                        // The following code ensures that the default Save File  
                        // dialog is not displayed. 
                    case DialogResult.No:
                        wb.Saved = true;
                        break;
                }
            }   

            isClosed = !cancel;
            // wb.Parent
        }

        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int returnValue = 0;

            if (args.Length != 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-E- excelHandler takes single XLXS as input");
                return -1;
            }
            string inputFile = args[0];

            if (!File.Exists(inputFile))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-E- Input File doesn't exist: {0}", inputFile);
                return -1;
            }

            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            try
            {
                Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(inputFile);
                xlApp.Visible = true;

                Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler Event_BeforeBookClose;

                Event_BeforeBookClose = new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler(app_WorkbookBeforeClose);
                xlApp.WorkbookBeforeClose += Event_BeforeBookClose;

                // || 
                while (!isClosed)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
                }

                //xlWorkBook.Close(true);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                xlApp.Quit();
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I debugged it further. Looks like my messageBox is not registering correct button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It was with `MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly` option in

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save the " +
                "changes you made to " + wb.FullName + "?", "Blizzard Excel",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Warning, 
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 
                MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
```

I changed it to following to get it working.

```
NativeWindow nw = new System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow();
           nw.AssignHandle(new IntPtr(wb.Parent.Hwnd));

DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(nw,"Do you want to save the " +
           "changes you made to " + wb.FullName + "?", "Blizzard Excel",
           MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning,
           MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
```

I am still not sure what was wrong with my initial code.